# Загрузка изображений. Безопасность

Tags: php, безопасность

Заголовок Content-Type можно подменить, getimagesize() тоже доверять нет смысла, так как файл может быть в формате GIF, JPEG, JPG, PNG, но и в тоже время php-скриптом, проверять расширение файла тоже нет смысла, т.к уже было сказано, что изображение может быть php-скриптом.

Интересуют все дельные советы по обеспечению безопасной загрузки изображений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое: непонятно, где, по-вашему, вообще происходит какая-то проблема с безопасностью. Второе:

> getimagesize() тоже доверять нет смысла, так как файл может быть в формате GIF, JPEG, JPG, PNG

Если файл действительно в формате GIF, JPEG, JPG, PNG, и getimagesize возвращает его пропорции, то, значит, это настоящий файл в формате GIF, JPEG, JPG, PNG. Может, коненчо, это рарджипег, но вы же не собираетесь исполнять его как PHP-скрипт?

Третье и последнее. Ну, загрузили вам скрипт с расширением `.gif`. Где в этом случае рушится безопасность? У вас сервер скармливает файлы с раширением `.gif` PHP-интерпретатору? Единственная проблема, которая здесь может быть - это проблема с [`cgi.fix_pathinfo` в php-fpm](http://habrahabr.ru/post/100961/), и пока вы живете на хостинге, этим должен заниматься хостер (и то это очень древний баг, который, вроде бы, пофиксили).

Пока вы работаете с файлом, как с изображением, и не выставляете в публичный доступ файлы, которые подпадают под правило "скормить интерпретатору" (т.е. файлы с расширением `.php`), ничего не произойдет.

Answer (score 3):

Apache отдает файлы с MIME-типом, определяемым по расширению. Поэтому если вы сами определяете расширение файла и не используете его где-то кроме тегов `img` и стилевых файлов, то вашему серверу ничего не грозит. Ваши клиенты в теории все еще могут пострадать от эксплойтов в браузерах, но это уже не ваша головная боль.

Ну и, разумеется, никогда не выполняйте `include` или `require` с пользовательскими данными.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на вопрос из другого ответа.

Проблема с безопасностью происходит на сервере.

Если файл действительно в формате GIF, JPEG, JPG, PNG, и getimagesize возвращает его пропорции, то, значит, это настоящий файл в формате GIF, JPEG, JPG, PNG, который в разделе метаданных может содержать РНР код.

Вопрос, как выполнить залитый код - это уже второй вопрос. Скажем, если у нас дырявый инклюд, то проще может оказаться заинклюдить лог файл. Но я бы всё равно не хотел бы иметь файл с потенциально опасным содержимым. Тем более, что апач с настройками по молчанию радостно исполнит пхп код из файла с названием xploit.php.jpg

Поэтому сам я считаю, что для среднего сайта (не занимающегося размещением фотографий), самый надежный способ - это полная переконвертация залитого изображения, типа той, что делается функцией imagecreatefromjpeg().

Answer (score 0):

Переконвертация загружаемого фото тоже не дает гарантий. Вот статья на эту тему http://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/472887.php

Советую запрещать на уровне сервера исполнение любых кодов (не только php) в загружаемых пользователем файлах (в т.ч. изображениях)

Помните что на 100% защититься невозможно - можно только максимально снизить риски))

UPD 29.03.16
Для серверов Apache в папку куда загружаются пользовательские файлы положить .htaccess примерного содержания:

```
php_flag engine 0 
AddType "text/html" .php .cgi .pl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7 .asp .jsp
```

Comment: Да ну, прямо уж таки невозможно. Просто загруженный файл, с каким бы расширением он ни был, кладите в такое место, откуда вы не будете его выполнять. А не складывайте всё в одну кучу. Вот и всё в общем-то. Ограничение «не грузить файлы с расширением .php» выглядит очень уж беззубо.

Comment: @VladD Вы очень уж близоруко ответ прочитали - не запрет на загрузку php файлов, а запрет исполнения кода php в загружаемых пользователем файлах. Например в папке загружаемых изображений .htaccess (если сервер Apache) примерного содержания:

php_flag engine 0
AddType "text/html" .php .cgi .pl .fcgi .fpl .phtml .shtml .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7 .asp .jsp

Это примерный вариант - в остальном гугл в помощь

PS. Если Вы уверены что можете защититься на 100% - Вам путь в лучшие мировые ИТ компании на огромную з/п

Comment: У меня нету опыта с PHP, но глядя из мира C#, я не вижу, где может быть проблема. Файлы, которые загружают пользователь — будь то даже исполнимые файлы — не могут исполниться на моей системе без моего, программиста, на то явного желания. Если я напишу плохую систему, и буду запускать все файлы, не думая о том, это мои собственные файлы, или они загружены пользователем, то очевидно проблем не избежать. Но если просто класть пользовательские файлы в каталог, откуда просто ничего не запускать — проблема должна быть решена на корню.